# Accessing a controller action through out the application in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm little bit new to Zend, I want to use a controller action through out the entire application automatically, I don't have a clear idea to how to use it, thought about init() method, action helpers, etc.

Comment: Not worth a full answer, but: Have a look at the manual about `FrontController`-Plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then instead of simply creating controller action create controllerAction Helper .  Here you can find more about it

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html

```
My_Helper_Magic extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{

public function preDispach()
{
     //code inside here will run for entire application automatically
}

}
```

In your bootstrap do

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new My_Helper_Magic());
```

In Response to comment .

It depends upon your 'code fragment' , If your code fragment does not required to know nothing about module , controller, action , base url then you can use Bootstrap init function

like

```
public function _initAlways()
{
//see how this function name is prefixed with _init hence it will be called by ZF //everytime. You can put your code fragment here 
//If your code fragment depends upon some stuff like baseurl then do action controller
// registration here instead 
 Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new My_Helper_Magic());

}
```

In Response To comment

You can save any instance of your object inside Zend_Registy and retrieve it whereever you like

Inside Bootstrap.php

```
public function _initSetup()
{
$object = new My_Custom_Object();
Zend_Registry::set('my_custom_object',$object);
}
```

Later in your view or controller do

```
$myObject = Zend_Registry::get('my_custom_object');  //to access it
```

Comment: say that i want to load and use some code fragment through out the application and in every controller it should be loaded automatically, how can I do that? through the bootstrap file?.

Comment: Hi, sorry to troubling you and thank you for ur quick response, i understand ur answer and need further clarification. actually what i want is to return an object automatically and use it anywhere such as view, controller. So would i be able to write an actin in the bootstrap file and use it in views or actions? if so how can i call the function in the view. thanks in advacne